# SQL function LEFT count without html tags

Tags: mysql

In my mySQL Database I have a field called `Text`. This text includes HTML tags. For Example:

```
<p>This is an Example</p>
```

On my Website I want to show the first 4 letters. If I do this query:

```
SELECT LEFT(text,4) AS text FROM aufgabe WHERE id LIKE ...
```

It shows me only the `T` from `This` because the function `LEFT` counts the HTML tags.

My Question is how can I show the complete 'This' and include the HTML tags?

Comment: As the problem is solely related to the mySQL query I've retagged this question for you

Comment: You need an HTML parser for this, and I probably wouldn't even be handling this from a query.

Answer (score 2):

You could use locate for find the position of `>`

```
select left(text, locate( '>'. text ), 4 ) AS text FROM aufgabe WHERE id LIKE
```

or if you need  the `<p>` tag

```
select left(text, locate( '<p>', text )+2, 4 ) AS text FROM aufgabe WHERE id LIKE
```

Comment: This unfortunately only works if only one HTML tag is prepended

Comment: this i what you have in your sample .. and based on this sample the answer  is right  ...  eventuallly  post a new question and comment me the related  link  antway answer  updated  with a first  suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show this '<p>This' or this '<p>This</p>'?

LEFT(text, 7) will work for the first one.

Comment: I need it in general, since sometimes other HTML tags are preceded